# Write datatable to excel template and adding backcolor to a row in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

In the ASP.Net application I am working on, there is a requirement to send out excel to client attached to a mail and I have create excel in server in order to send it out as an attachment and office is not installed in server so I cannot use Microsoft.office.interop.excel ,the excel has image and some text and columns are fixed so I thought of making it as a template and writing Data table to it, and I want to give some back color to a row and wrap text for columns.

Can anyone show me how to accomplish this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4):

EPPlus is great http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use Open XML SDK

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2008/11/25/using-the-open-xml-sdk-to-work-with-excel-files.aspx

http://lateral8.com/articles/2010/3/5/openxml-sdk-20-export-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx